# DXA 2.0 issues getting static content

Tags: dxa, content-delivery, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

In SDL 8.5 we uploaded an mp4 file with size 17 MB. The size of the file in the target folder of the DXA 2.0 Java application is only 5 MB. The DXA-application shows the stack-trace beneath this post while retrieving the mp4.

We checked the logs of the SDL CD services, but could not find anything.

What could be the cause of this problem?

> WARN  c.s.w.c.i.i.StaticContentInterceptor - Issues getting the static
>   content /nl/media/aow-in-4stappen_tcm378-526931.mp4
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException:
>   java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the
>   software in your host machine     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:356)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:815)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:720)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:391)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:369)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
>     at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2147)   at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2102)     at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2123)    at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2078)     at
>   com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.interceptor.StaticContentInterceptor.preHandle(StaticContentInterceptor.java:138)
>     at
>   com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.interceptor.StaticContentInterceptor.preHandle(StaticContentInterceptor.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:134)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:958)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    Suppressed:
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException:
>   java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the
>   software in your host machine         at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:356)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:815)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:310)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:263)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.close(CoyoteOutputStream.java:157)
>         at
>   com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.interceptor.StaticContentInterceptor.preHandle(StaticContentInterceptor.java:139)
>         ... 38 common frames omitted    Caused by: java.io.IOException: An
>   established connection was aborted by the software in your host
>   machine       at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)        at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)       at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)       at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)       at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)        at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134)      at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1259)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:670)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:450)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:388)
>         at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:644)
>         at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:121)
>         at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:235)
>         at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:541)        at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:351)
>         ... 43 common frames omitted Caused by: java.io.IOException: An
>   established connection was aborted by the software in your host
>   machine   at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)    at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1259)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:670)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:450)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:388)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:644)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:235)
>     at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:541)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:351)
>     ... 48 common frames omitted

Comment: we are getting the same issues, were you able to resolve it

Comment: we are using 9.1 CME and dxa 2.0, below is the exception :
1) javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
2.) javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe